# Não acha classe do Google Maps

Tags: android, google, maps

Estou tentando carregar uma `FragmentActivity`, que carrega o mapa do Google Maps. Estava funcionando, e parou do nada.

Eu quero abrir ela através de um botão, mas assim que carrega a activity com esse botão, já dá esse erro no monitor.

> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class
>   'br.com.studios.conselhoprofissional.GoogleMap.Mapa', referenced from
>   method
>   br.com.studios.conselhoprofissional.Telas_Menu_Lateral.Denuncia.getLocalizacao

E quando eu clico no botão pra abrir:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   br.com.studios.conselhoprofissional.GoogleMap.Mapa at
>   br.com.studios.conselhoprofissional.Telas_Menu_Lateral.Denuncia.getLocalizacao(Denuncia.java:59)

No gradle tem

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
```

e o `muldexenable` está `true`.

Como resolver isso?

Comment: @acklay na classe denuncia tem :     public void getLocalizacao(View view) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Mapa.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

Comment: O que tem na linha 59 da classe Denuncia?

Comment: método getLocalizacao.